# Icon not displaying on screen android using react-native-vector-icons

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, expo, create-react-native-app

I am using [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app). I want to use [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

But its not showing anything on android screen (I am viewing it on expo app)

Here is what I did:

App.js:

```
       const Courses = TabNavigator({
  ReactCourses: { screen: ReactCourses },
  NativeCourses: { screen: NativeCourses },
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    swipeEnabled: true,
    showIcon:true,
  },
});
```

ReactCourses.js:

```
     import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
    static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'React Courses',
    tabBarIcon:({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon
          name={'home'}
          size={26}
          style={[styles.icon, {color: tintColor}]} />
      )

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Create React Native App, it's not possible to use `react-native link` with native module packages. Because CRNA projects are loaded in the Expo client app, you'll want to follow the [relevant documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons.html) to get vector icons working in your project.

Also, make sure that you're using the Expo preset in `.babelrc`. It should look like [the one provided in the template project](https://github.com/expo/new-project-template/blob/master/.babelrc).

Answer (score 10):

Add the following things in android/app/build.gradle

**apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"**

And then execute the command

**react-native run-android**

Answer (score -1):

I think what you did is just a half thing, so after running `npm install` did you link the project with the third party's native code by running `react-native link`? if yes, did you rebuild the project by going to android studio and hit play button?if yes then just restart your packager and we are good to go...

Cheers :)

Comment: Yes ,I did react-native link but why do I need android studio to rebuild .I think create-react-native-app tool is made so that there is no need for android and xcode.

Comment: Also I did `npm run android` and ran the app in android emulator...still facing same issue.

Comment: did you rebuild the project?

Comment: Please note that Create React Native App doesn't support using `react-native link` unless you've ejected already, which OP didn't say they did.